# jquery: replacing div with URL get request instead of a showing a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

new to jquery here and I've been learning how to show/hide divs. I'd like to take it a step further and be able to replace a div with an AJAX call instead of showing a hidden div.

In this example I've been working on, the 'expand' button hides div.post-small and shows div.post-big

http://jsfiddle.net/ejwFr/

How would I begin to modify this so that the 'expand' button instead hides div.post-small and replaces the contents of div.post with an AJAX request (which would return a hypothetical div.post-big-ajax)

Thanks a lot for any insights!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element.

**Example**

```
$("div.expand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.post-small').hide();
    $(this).parent().next().load('ajax/content.html');        
});
```

`Load()` fetches data from the server via an AJAX call and sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I actually do need the .post-small to be hidden, and for the ajax to load into .post-big so that a user can 'close' .post-big and show .post-small again. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's actually the way I originally answered my question until I saw what you had typed in your question.  I went ahead and reverted my answer back to the way I originally thought and the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something [like this jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/ejwFr/2/)...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this which checks if the div has content before loading in the html through ajax if it's needed. The load method retrieves the data and sets the html content of the element to what has been returned.

```
$("div.expand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.post-small').hide();

    //if content exists, ajax has been executed just show the div
    if ($(this).parents('.post').find('.post-big').text().length > 0) {
        $(this).parent('.post').find('.post-big').show("slow")
    }
    else {
        //perform the ajax call to the page set up to return the content
        $(this).parent('.post').find('.post-big').load('ajax/content.html');
        $(this).parent('.post').find('.post-big').show("slow")
    }

});
```

can also be seen in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FMjum/

Comment: thanks for the help, is there a way to have jsfiddle load an actual ajax response, right now nothing shows up

Comment: I've been trying to work that out myself, i'm relatively new to jsfiddle myself ^^

Comment: got it $(this).parents('.post').load('/echo/html/', { html: 'Hello!' });
});